# PuppeteerSharp - Strong name signature could not be verified. The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed

Tags: c#, .net, webdriver, puppeteer-sharp

I have installed PuppeteerSharp package to my MVC project and project build successfully but while opening the page getting the below error message:

***Could not load file or assembly 'PuppeteerSharp' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key.***

I have tried to remove all dll files from the bin folder and build the project but still getting the same error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: One thing that could be a problem here is what is in your .csproj file (the project definition file). Take a look in your project directory and open the .csproj file in an editor (f.i. Notepad++). Find the assembly in it and remove it from the .csproj (keep a copy handy if you have to revert your change). In my experience most of the time that helps. But it could still be something else.